# How to reverting back to the last version rstan (version 2.19.3) from (2.21.1) in R?

Tags: r, rstan

I have the same issue [BRM model compiling but returning model object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63025052/brm-model-compiling-but-returning-model-object)

How can I reverting back to the last version (2.19.3) from (2.21.1)?

My R programming skills are not good.

I tried below code.

```
packageurl <- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rstan/rstan_2.19.3.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

And console space replied...

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘rstan’ is in use and will not be installed
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need first to unload the package:

```
detach("package:rstan", unload = TRUE)
```

or even uninstall it:

```
remove.packages("rstan")
```

and then you can use your command, which should be correct:

```
packageurl <- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rstan/rstan_2.19.3.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I attempt to `remove.packages("rstan")` and next `packageurl <- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rstan/rstan_2.19.3.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos = NULL, type = "source")`. But Console space enters infinite loop and never finish. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: @GiTaeSeo Maybe there's some network error? So try to unload (`detach`) the package, download the archive source from the [URL](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rstan/rstan_2.19.3.tar.gz) above to have it locally and try to install it from your disk (or use RStudio's interface).

Comment: Unfortunately, Result does not change..I'm not sure how to express this problem(=error) cuz my English is not good enough. i will try to solve this problem again tomorrow. I appreciate your answer.really thanks

Comment: And plus, I faced this problem by reviewing the code attached to the paper("An introduction to using Bayesian linear regression with clinical data") - (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0005796716302364?via%3Dihub )